# backbone.js doesn't fire click event on DOM element

Tags: backbone.js

I can't fire the click event on DOM element.

This is my js file: app.js. I'm pretty sure I'm missing something or doing wrong here but I can't figured out where.

```js
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    el: $('body'),

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'sayHello');
    },

    events: {
        'click .link': 'sayHello'
    },

    sayHello: function(e) {
        alert('Hello!');
    }

});

var app = new App();
```

and this is my HTML file: index.htm.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
    <title></title>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/underscore-min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/backbone-min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/app.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<a href="#" class="link">Click here!</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

This was admittingly trickily. Think through the code logically. Your JS script is in your `head`.

The jQuery selector `el: $('body')` does not exist yet. (JavaScript executes immediately). Try doing `el: 'body'`.

Comment: If I move the scripts out the `head` it works but I want to keep the scripts in the `head`. The script works if I put the `Backbone.View` inside `$(function() { ... });` so when the DOM is ready, I'm pretty sure because the `link` already exists in the DOM and is not added by a `Backbone.View`.

Comment: @MassimilianoMarini: But the problem is that `$('body')` doesn't match anything when the view "class" is being built (which is when the `$('body')` function call is executed) so your view ends up with the wrong `el` and nothing works. If you use `el: 'body'` then Backbone will look up the `el` when you instantiate the view.

Comment: @muistooshort `el: body` works If I put scripts before `</body>` tag. So this is a good practice and I'm going this way.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your view on dom load event.

```
var App = Backbone.View.extend({

    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, 'sayHello'); // you don't need this for your code to work
    },

    events: {
        'click .link': 'sayHello'
    },

    sayHello: function(e) {
        alert('Hello!');
    }

});


$(function(){
  var app = new App({el: $("body")});
});
```